# Where are VSTS retained releases stored?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using an on-premises VSTS build agent to build and release my application. The retention configuration for the release is set to 30 days, and in the VSTS web site I can see there are 30 days worth of releases retained. However, I was expecting to see the .zip files for the retained release somewhere in the build agents working folder, but cannot find them anywhere.

Can someone tell me where the releases are stored?

Comment: Do you have a upload artifacts tasks in your definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSTS releases stores in team services server and you can only access through Releases Tab.

- If you want to retention the release earlier then 30 days, you can specify **Days to retain a release** with bigger number between 31 and 365.

  As **Days to retain a release** option description:

  > Set the number of days to retain a release deployed to this
  >   environment. Any release can be retained for at least 1 day and a
  >   maximum of 365 days.
- If you want to view the artifacts related to a release, you can publish build artifacts to a network shared path. In the related build definition, select **Artifact Type** as **File share** for [Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts) task. So the artifacts will always be retained locally.