# Azure DevOps Server 2022 replacement for prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent

Tags: azure-devops-server-2022

I have an Azure DevOps Server 2022 database that has grown out of control.  I have deleted a lot of old content that should have reduced the size of my database by several hundred gigabytes, but I suspect that the content has simply been marked for deletion, rather than actually deleted from the database.

I have read this post regarding the same problem in Azure DevOps Server 2020:
[Azure DevOps Server database growing out of control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525308/azure-devops-server-database-growing-out-of-control)

However, one key stored procedure, prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent appears to be absent from the database in DevOps Server 2022. is there a replacement for this stored procedure in DevOps Server 2022, or else is there a new way to release the space consumed by deleted content?